# How to add exceptions to space before and after a paragraph?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have defined four paragraph styles and would like the space between them to work "in pairs".

- First paragraph (no indent)
- Heading 1/2/3

I would like

- No space between Body text and Headings 2/3, but space after Heading 1
- No space between any of the Headings if they happen in sequence

By setting up "space before" and "space after" there's always one point above that is not met. Is there any way to do this?

**An example:**

Top arrow should have space, middle arrow should have no space, bottom arrow should have space. The space before "adjuvant ..." is correct.

[image]

Adding "space after" the first paragraph style doesn't work because it adds space between it and the related body text style (with indent).

Do you create styles for every option? like first paragraph, first paragraph with space, last paragraph, last paragraph before bullet points so no space, etc... ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have the following styles:

- **Heading 1** with *Space Before* and *Space After*,
- **Heading 2** with *Space Before*,
- **Heading 3** with *Space Before*,
- **First Paragraph** with no spacing

This will work fine until you start having multiple headings right after each other.

In my opinion multiple headings right after each other doesn't really belong in classic typography and should normally be avoided if possible. Content-wise it seems a bit strange to add a heading and then have nothing to say and jump on to the next level immediately and it can also give you some trouble design-wise depending on your styling.

Nonetheless it's not an uncommon sight in for example reports and scientific papers, and I totally acknowledge that designers should find ways to make it work.

I can't see how your problem could be solved with only four styles. You can't take advantage of the *Space Between Paragraphs Using Same Style* setting as it will only work if it's the exact same style, not if it's a style *Based On* on the style.

Of course you would always want to have as few styles as possible, but sometimes you have to accept that adding a few specific styles can solve some local problems even if they only occur a couple of times in your document.

So one of several possible solutions would be to add the following styles:

- **Heading 1 Before Heading** (based on **Heading 1**) without *Space After*
- **Heading 2 After Heading** (based on **Heading 2**) without *Space Before*
- **Heading 3 After Heading** (based on **Heading 3**) without *Space Before*

(I'm always trying to avoid naming styles according to their *appearance*, but rather try to describe their *function*. Perhaps you'll change the design later so having "space before" in the name won't make sense anymore.)